# Tab bar Controller launch time first-view-Controller view position down 20px

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Tab bar Controller  launch time first-view-Controller view position down 20px After going to next controller came to first viewcontroller view position goes up 20px ,I am using storyboards

when launch time first view Controller
[image: when launch time first view before tab to next]

after tab next and came to same tab
[image: after tab next and came to same tab]

How to clear space between navigation bar and view

TabControler setup in storyboard
[image]

Comment: show your storyboard setup instead of these ?  tell me if you have scroll view on first tab?

Comment: What are your simulated bar metrics in xib/storyboard?

Comment: I guess you might have set topLayoutGuides of the two viewControllers differently which associated with first and the next tab. Please check both are properly set.

Comment: @pawan i want to use scroll view but not now ,i add your asked info

Comment: @ILikeIOS try with  goto -> TabControler setup in storyboard ->view controller (as i can see here) -> un check adjust scroll view insets.

Comment: @pawan not working any other way

Answer (score 0):

Try unchecking '**Adjust Scrollview Insets**' on Storyboard or do it programmatically in '**viewDidLoad**':

```
if #available(iOS 11, *) {
    myScroll.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
} else {
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```

Answer (score -3):

That could be a bug in iOS7. Try switching off autolayout.

Comment: why dont you post it in comment ? if it help user then you can post it as answer.